# Is it possible to make it run any faster?

Tags: c#, performance, parallel-processing

I've tried everything, added a special Parallel For cycle, but it's not just fast enough.
Is there a way to make it run faster?
I know it's possible to these computations on GPU too, but I don't have any experiences with that.

For comparison, if it's using its full potential or not pc specs here:

> CPU: AMD Ryzen 5 3400G with Radeon Vega Graphics 3.70 GHz
>
> GPU: AMD Radeon rx580 8GB

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Timers;


    namespace MyProgram
    {
        public partial class Form1 : Form
        {
            public Form1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            } 
           
            int[] code;
            int time = 0;
            Char[] characters = new Char[] 
            {
                'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i','j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z',
                '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9' 
            };
    
            String passTry = "";       
    
            private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                code = null;
                time = 0;
                passTry = "";
                code = new int[int.Parse(LengthBox.Text)];
                OutputBox.AppendText("Trying to break password...");
                OutputBox.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);
              
    
                Parallel.For(0, int.Parse(LengthBox.Text), i =>
                {
                    code[i] = 0;
                });
    
                timer1.Enabled = true;
    
               Task.Run(() =>
    
               {
    
                    while (passTry!=passOrig.Text)
                    {
                            Parallel.For(0, (code.Length-1), o =>
                            {
                                
                                if (code[o] > 34 && o < code.Length)
                                {
                                    code[o] = 0;
                                    code[o+1] += 1; 
                                }
    
                                passTry = "";
    
                                Parallel.For(0, (code.Length), i =>
                                {
                                    if (passTry.Length < code.Length)
                                    {
                                        passTry +=characters[code[i]];
                                    }
                                });
    
                           
                            });
    
                            code[0] = code[0] + 1;
                    }
               });
            }
        
          
    
    
            private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
              
            }
    
            private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                timeLbl.Text = (time/10).ToString() + "s";
                time++;
    
                if (passTry.Length == code.Length)
                {
                    OutputBox.AppendText("Trying password " + passTry + "...");
                    OutputBox.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);
    
                    if (passOrig.Text == passTry)
                    {
                        OutputBox.AppendText("Success, Password found " + passTry);
                        OutputBox.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);
                        timer1.Enabled = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        
        }
    }
```

My code takes a simple brute force algorithm of a combination lock. Starts at 0 0 0 0.
Then add one to the first digit and when the digit meets maximum resets it and adds one to the next digit and again and when the next digit reaches the maximum add one to the next one again and again until the result of converted characters joined to string doesn't match string **passOrig.Text**.

```
Combination lock+ conversion
    
    0 0 0 0 = A A A A
    1 0 0 0 = B A A A
    2 0 0 0 = C A A A 
    3 0 0 0 = D A A A
    0 1 0 0 = A B A A
    1 1 0 0 = B B A A
    2 1 0 0 = C B A A
    3 1 0 0 = D B A A
    0 2 0 0 = A C A A


//code to string conversion

Parallel.For(0, (code.Length), i =>
                            {
                                if (passTry.Length < code.Length)
                                {
                                    passTry +=characters[code[i]];
                                }
                            });
```

Edit: This is only the first part after deploying the original password won't be known. The only known value will be is it a password or not(true or false) thx for all answers there are 2 interesting answers, but I think I currently don't have brain capacity to understand them.

Comment: Nesting `Parallel` isn't really a great idea here; but even worse: you're using shared state (`code[...]`) between parallel operations; right now, the outcome isn't even well-defined; if this was me, I'd forget about tumblers, and just represent the space by integers (0-9999 presumably) - then I'd just partition that space into some number of chunks - maybe 20, and just do parallel on those 20 chunks - so I only have 20 parallel operations; then I'd probably use a stackalloc span for each of the 20, and rorate through the options in that chunk

Comment: You do have a lot of wasted time when you do `someString += someOtherString`. Each time you concatenate strings it recreate the object. When doing a lot of string manipulation you should favor the `StringBuilder` class instead. Check out their documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.stringbuilder?view=net-5.0)

Comment: Since you know the password - `passOrig.Text` - I would sugget parsing the string character by character, so brute force the first character, if you found the correct one, go to the next one and so on.

Comment: Going per index seems fast enough for my taste: https://dotnetfiddle.net/AbFQX9

Comment: Here a version with my code resulting in false: https://dotnetfiddle.net/MKC7lT

Comment: This has got to be one of the most awkward and long winded ways of "finding a number between 0 and 9999" I've ever seen. I should easily be possible to rewrite it to crack it so fast, the windows clock wouldnt even have time to update from one 16ms block to the next - how slow is "just not fast enough" ? Convert your characters to a single number, increment it (hint; ints naturally go to 0010 if you add 1 to 0009) and if it's equal to the target (also a char to int), stop

Comment: FYI you don't need to set all the values in the `code` array to 0 as they will default to that when you create the array.

Comment: @CaiusJard how? Alphabet.Length >9 How can I manage to keep value readable in one big number when there's 2 digit number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried not to overthink it and wrote this single-threaded version and on my laptop it seems to be hundreds of time faster then what is shown in the question.

I tested with "zzzz" because it's the worst case for my implementation.

My version is taking ~0.1s.

Your version is taking >10s.

```
static void Naive(string password)
{
    var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    var characters = new string(new Char[]
    {
        'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i','j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9' 
    });
    int characterLength = characters.Length;
    
    // Let's make the password an array of numbers
    byte[] passwordAsNumbers = password.Select(c =>(byte)characters.IndexOf(c)).ToArray();

    var attempt = new byte[password.Length];

    Find(0);
    var found = new string(attempt.Select(i => characters[i]).ToArray());
    var elapsed = sw.Elapsed;

    bool Find(int index)
    {
        if (index >= attempt.Length) return false;

        for (byte i = 0; i < characterLength; i++)
        {
            attempt[index] = i;
            if (attempt.SequenceEqual(passwordAsNumbers)) return true;
            if (Find(index + 1)) return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you hit it right. Your solution seems to be usable for my case. I was thinking about using binary numbers but didn't know how to add one to it. Thanks, I will try to integrate it into my program thx.

Comment: @Acryfoxczlp - don't understand why this solution seems usable and my solution in the comments isn't, in both cases the password is known, both go per index, my solution is even faster, maybe you can explain the difference to me? As a side note, this answer scales terrible with long strings, eg. I tried my solution vs this with a 104 character "zzz..." string and those are the results on my machine TryBreak 3ms / Naive gave up waiting after 2+ hours, the code I used to test: https://dotnetfiddle.net/GbDzB9

Comment: ... (cont) not trying to flex, "hey, mine is better", just want to know what the difference is, since I fail to see any

Comment: @RandRandom It's not that your solution is bad it's ok for this case, but in practical use, you don't know the result password we're trying to find it out from all the combinations. We have only output true or false I know you can just set characters, but then there's no difference between just copying it in from the original one. In practice, you don't know the password. Some solutions aren't usable for my case some are so advanced I don't even understand them I have to take the one I understand and work for my case. I appreciate every answer.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so let's assume when it's live you'll have a method like this:

```
public bool IsItTheCombination(string combo) =>
  return combo=="FEDC"; //returns true if the input is FEDC
```

You're saying you want to start at AAAA then try AAAB, AAAC, AAAD and so on. After AAAJ -> AABA, because J is the 9th letter if A is the 0th letter. And eventually, after 7654 (FEDC) guesses you'll hit the right combo. You don't know what FEDC actually is.. you'll just call it over and over with different strings and get a true or false

So really this is just like counting, 0000, 0001, 0002, .., 0009, 0010. Except we're using letter characters A instead of number characters 0.

---

Let's have a loop that goes from 0 to 9999 - that's all the combinations

```
for(int x = 0; x <= 9999; x++){

}
```

Now we just need to turn 0000 into AAAA. Good thing then that chars and numbers in C# are interchangeable

How do we break an integer into its thousands, hundreds, tens and units? Could make it a string, and pull it apart.. We could also do it with math.. Let's do math.

- 123***4*** divide by 1 modulo 10 is ***4***.
- 12***3***4 divide by 10 modulo 10 is ***3***.
- 1***2***34 divide by 100 modulo 10 is ***2***.
- ***1***234 divide by 1000 modulo 10 is ***1***.

We don't need to divide by 1, or modulo after doing the divide by 1000 (non ops)

```
for(int x = 0; x <= 9999; x++){

  int thousands = x/1000;
  int hundreds = (x/100)%10;
  int tens = (x/10)%10;
  int units = x%10;

}
```

So when x = 1234, we now have 4 variables that represent each of the 4 numbers. To turn them into a character, all you have to do is add whatever character you want, and cast it to a char:

```
charc c = (char)('A' + 0);
```

A+0 is A. A+1 is B. A+2 is C..

```
for(int x = 0; x <= 9999; x++){

  char thousands = (char)('A' + x/1000);
  char hundreds = (char)('A' + (x/100)%10);
  char tens = (char)('A' + (x/10)%10);
  char units = (char)('A' + x%10);

}
```

You now hove 4 chars. Turning chars into strings is easy, and it's even easier if those chars are in an array because we can use the `new string(char[])`  constructor

Array mode:

```
char[] guess = new char[4];
for(int x = 0; x <= 9999; x++){

  guess[0] = (char)('A' + x/1000);
  guess[1] = (char)('A' + (x/100)%10);
  guess[2] = (char)('A' + (x/10)%10);
  guess[3] = (char)('A' + x%10);

}
```

Then just see if the guess is right:

```
char[] guess = new char[4];
for(int x = 0; x <= 9999; x++){

  guess[0] = (char)('A' + x/1000);
  guess[1] = (char)('A' + (x/100)%10);
  guess[2] = (char)('A' + (x/10)%10);
  guess[3] = (char)('A' + x%10);

  var guessStr = new string(guess);
  if(IsItTheCombination(guessStr)){
    Console.WriteLine("The combo is " + guessStr);
  }
}
```

This can, of course, be altered for any length of guessing. It's also easier to work backwards, because you just divide by 10 each time to cut another digit off:

```
  guess[3] = (char)('A' + x%10);
  x=x/10;
  guess[2] = (char)('A' + x%10);
  x=x/10;
  guess[1] = (char)('A' + x%10);
  x=x/10;
  guess[0] = (char)('A' + x%10);
```

You can see that all the operations become the same: mod 10, assign, divide 10 over and over. This means an inner loop can handle our logic:

```
char[] guess = new char[20];
for(int x = (int)Math.Pow(10, guess.Length-1) - 1; x >= 0; x--){

  int num = x;                                   //take a copy of x because we'll modify it with division and we don't want to lose our place in the brute forcing

  
  guess[guess.Length - 1] = (char)('A' + x%10);  //do the right most digit as a special case (no division)
  for(int c = guess.Length - 2; c >= 0; c--){
    num = num/10;                                //cut a digit off
    guess[c] = (char)('A' + num%10);             //what is the rightmost digit?
  }

  var guessStr = new string(guess);
  if(IsItTheCombination(guessStr)){
    Console.WriteLine("The combo is " + guessStr);
  }
}
```